# How to specify logging level in apps scirpt?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I understand that we have logging feature with [console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) api. But is there any way I can set up log level such info, debug ,err so that I can control what messages are displayed?

Comment: I was asking, how can you set the level in the program, so that even if you write console.log(), console.info(), they will be omitted when you set the log level to 'ERROR'. Just like how you do with log4j.

Answer (score 2):

For logging to Stack Driver you use the [`console`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) class which includes methods such as: (info, warn, log, error).

So for example you would write:

> `console.warn("This is a warning!")`

or

> `console.info("This is informative.")`

or

> `console.log("This is a log")`

or

> `console.error("This message is formatted as an error in the log.")`

Comment: but, suppose with log4j configuration, if we set logger level to 'INFO' , debug messages will not be displayed right?  Can we set the level here?

Comment: There is quite extensive possibilities of logging, see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs. As far as the `console` class goes I'm afraid there is no such configuration attr